# Haven't received weekly newsletter for 4 weeks

Tags: bug, newsletter

I'm only subscribed to one newsletter (Stack Overflow weekly), but I haven't received it since Tuesday 2nd October.

The subscriptions tab on my profile show I am subscribed. Is there a known problem?

Comment: This is not a known issue - I don't repro on other sites but it's possible we're having trouble on SO specifically (due to scale). Thanks for the alert - we'll dig in tomorrow morning.

Comment: Still digging here but it looks like we're having some issues with large batches of emails (which SO newsletters almost always are). Tuesdays are the worst (when you're scheduled to get your email) so it very badly affects all the things. Should get to the bottom of it today!

Comment: @DeanWard did you ever get to the bottom of this? It still seems that the newsletter often fails to reach me!